# Converting script from C# to javascript/nodejs to print image to POS Printer

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I have really hard time converting this from C# to a javascript/nodejs script.
This script will be used in a nodejs server and there are so many npm modules that could help to convert this, but I dont really know much about C#. So there are issues with the bytes variables.
This script is used to print to POS printer a bmp image via ESCP commands.

Mostly I cannot figure out how to convert them in node/javascript the following lines:
**BitArray dots = data.Dots;

byte[] width = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Width);

...

byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

return logo + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);**

**Below is the whole script**

```
 public string GetLogo()
{
    string logo = "";
    if (!File.Exists(@"C:\bitmap.bmp"))
        return null;
     BitmapData data = GetBitmapData(@"C:\bitmap.bmp");
     BitArray dots = data.Dots;
     byte[] width = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Width);

     int offset = 0;
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);

     bw.Write((char)0x1B);
     bw.Write('@');

     bw.Write((char)0x1B);
     bw.Write('3');
     bw.Write((byte)24);

     while (offset < data.Height)
     {
         bw.Write((char)0x1B);
         bw.Write('*');         // bit-image mode
         bw.Write((byte)33);    // 24-dot double-density
         bw.Write(width[0]);  // width low byte
         bw.Write(width[1]);  // width high byte

         for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; ++x)
         {
             for (int k = 0; k < 3; ++k)
             {
                 byte slice = 0;
                 for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b)
                 {
                     int y = (((offset / 8) + k) * 8) + b;
                     // Calculate the location of the pixel we want in the bit array.
                     // It'll be at (y * width) + x.
                     int i = (y * data.Width) + x;

                     // If the image is shorter than 24 dots, pad with zero.
                     bool v = false;
                     if (i < dots.Length)
                     {
                         v = dots[i];
                     }
                     slice |= (byte)((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 - b));
                 }

                 bw.Write(slice);
             }
         }
         offset += 24;
         bw.Write((char)0x0A);
     }
     // Restore the line spacing to the default of 30 dots.
     bw.Write((char)0x1B);
     bw.Write('3');
     bw.Write((byte)30);

     bw.Flush();
     byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
     return logo + Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
}

public BitmapData GetBitmapData(string bmpFileName)
{
    using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(bmpFileName))
    {
        var threshold = 127;
        var index = 0;
        double multiplier = 570; // this depends on your printer model. for Beiyang you should use 1000
        double scale = (double)(multiplier/(double)bitmap.Width);
        int xheight = (int)(bitmap.Height * scale);
        int xwidth = (int)(bitmap.Width * scale);
        var dimensions = xwidth * xheight;
        var dots = new BitArray(dimensions);

        for (var y = 0; y < xheight; y++)
        {
            for (var x = 0; x < xwidth; x++)
            {
                var _x = (int)(x / scale);
                var _y = (int)(y / scale);
                var color = bitmap.GetPixel(_x, _y);
                var luminance = (int)(color.R * 0.3 + color.G * 0.59 + color.B * 0.11);
                dots[index] = (luminance < threshold);
                index++;
            }
        }

        return new BitmapData()
        {
            Dots = dots,
            Height = (int)(bitmap.Height*scale),
            Width = (int)(bitmap.Width*scale)
        };
    }
}

public class BitmapData
{
    public BitArray Dots
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: What error u getting in console

Comment: I get a lot of errors, because I am not able to succesfully convert this C# script to a node/javascript script. I am not sure how to handle the byte variables in javascript.